# install php-rdkafka on ubuntu20.04

Tags: apache2, php, compiling

I am trying to install php-rdkafka lib:
https://arnaud.le-blanc.net/php-rdkafka-doc/phpdoc/index.html
on my ubuntu 20.04, php 8.0. With php8.0-dev package installed.

the suggested installation via PECL give me this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Config.php on line 2095

So I turn to manual installation, and after finish it without no error, when php.ini try to load the module give me this message:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: rdkafka: Unable to initialize module
> Module compiled with module API=20210902
> PHP    compiled with module API=20200930
> These options need to match
> in Unknown on line 0

How can I solve it?
thanks

Comment: I would ask the people that made this php-rdkafka lib that question.

Comment: i have read similar question where the suggestion is to update modules, in my case, i can understand what i can update!

Comment: I think that the errors mean that the thing you are trying to install has invalid PHP code. For example, PHP does not like curly braces (or "{ }") for some reason anymore. If you can find the thing's repository and edit the code, you can, but I would just recommend finding an alternative to the program that you are trying to run and install.